# Переменная в XSLT не сохраняет порядок элементов

Tags: xml, xslt

Я пытаюсь выполнить xsl шаблон с помощью libxslt, но получаю совсем неинтуитивный вывод.
У меня есть такая XML:

```
<ancestor0>
  <ancestor1>
    <ancestor2>
      <node1></node1>
    </ancestor2>
  </ancestor1>
</ancestor0>
```

Такая XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="node1">
    <xsl:variable name="save" select="./ancestor::*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="name($save[1])"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

При выполнении я расчитываю увидеть ancestor2, но выводится ancestor0. Что интересно, если этот же шаблон выполнить с помощью MSXML, то выведется ancestor2. Есть ли возможность сохранять в переменной элементы в обратном порядке?

Я ожидаю, что результатом выражения select="./ancestor::*" будет node-set с таким порядком:

```
ancestor2
ancestor1
ancestor0
```

Но получается такой порядок:

```
ancestor0
ancestor1
ancestor2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15201279/1016033 вот тут Майкл Кей пишет что вообще-то результат селектора это nodeset в котором порядок не определён.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте желаемый результат к вашему вопросу.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать что выполняя выражение select="./ancestor::*" я не могу расчитывать на какой-то конкретный порядок элементов?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее XPath выражение:

```
./parent::*
```

Comment: Да, я понимаю что это поможет. Но меня интересует почему при сохранении в переменную обратный порядок теряется. В MSXML это работает, а вот в LIBXSLT нет. Вот мне и интересно, какая из двух библиотек отрабатывает более правильно.

Comment: @andrei.aliashkevich - как уже написал Alexey Ten: порядок не определён. Поэтому и тот, и тот вариант правильный. Каждая библиотека может выбрать свой внутренний формат представления nodeset.